# How to open Bootstrap modal pop-up one after other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

In mvc application, I have a HTML table on which data is created on load using Ajax. This HTML table consists of N number of records, I have applied Pagination to the table using Jquery so that only 10 records are added to a single page on the table.

Now the first column of the html table is checkbox which means that if I select the checkbox in the header all the records in the particular page of the table would be selected. I have few buttons on the top which does certain functionalities among them is a delete button which deletes all the records which are selected from the table. Now the problem is that for each records a Modal Popup should show up asking "Do you want to delete the records of {somename}?". I have a confirm button and a cancel button.

On click of "Confirm" the particular record details would be deleted and then again a new pop-up should display asking confirmation to delete the records. Like wise if I click Cancel then the current popup should be closed and new one should open asking confirmation to delete the records.

Following is the code that I did

```
//Create a modal popup
function BootstrapModalPopUp(modalId, ButtonConfirmID, ButtonCancelID, ButtonText, modalTitle, modalBody) {
    var popUpContent = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal' + modalId + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">'
   + '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">'
   + '<div class="modal-content">'
       + '<div class="modal-header">'
           + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'
           + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalTitle + '</h4>'
       + '</div>'
       + '<div class="modal-body">'
           + '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' + modalBody + '</h4>'
       + '</div>'
       + '<div class="modal-footer">';

    if (ButtonConfirmID != '') {
        popUpContent += '<button id="btn' + ButtonConfirmID + '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>'
                + '<button id="btn' + ButtonCancelID + '" type="button" onclick="modalpopupcancel()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">' + ButtonText + '</button>'
    }
    else {
        popUpContent += '<button id="btn' + ButtonCancelID + '" type="button" onclick="modalpopupcancel()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">' + ButtonText + '</button>'
    }
    + '</div></div></div></div>';
    $('#myModalPopups').append(popUpContent);
}


//On click of the button
    function EmailConfirmationSubmit(buttonName) {
        $('#' + buttonName).click(function () {
            //Getting the number of CheckBox
            var $chkboxes = $('#tblMemberList').find("tr input[type='checkbox']:checked");
            //Getting the ID (checked value) from the CheckBox and storing in Array
            var checkBoxVals = $chkboxes.map(function () { return $(this).attr('id'); }).toArray();

            //remove the first element of the checkbox. This is the header of the checkbox which we dont need to show the pop up for
            if ($.inArray('memberListHeaderCheckBox', checkBoxVals) > -1) {
                checkBoxVals.splice($.inArray("memberListHeaderCheckBox", checkBoxVals), 1);
            }

            var ModalIdBeforeCreation = 'DeleteConfirmation';
            var ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation = '_DeleteConfirm';
            var ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation = '_DeleteCancel';

            //Checking the Array whether it is not empty
            if (!isArrayEmpty(checkBoxVals)) {
                //Loop through each selected checkbox
                checkBoxVals.forEach(function (CheckBox) {

                    //Get id and name of the check box. The name is the pension ID
                    var CheckBoxID = $("#" + CheckBox).val();
                    var CheckBoxName = $("#" + CheckBox).attr('name').toString();

                    var ModalId = ModalIdBeforeCreation + CheckBoxID;
                    var ModalConfirmID = ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation + CheckBoxID;
                    var ModalCancelID = ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation + CheckBoxID;
                    var ModalMessage = 'Do you want to delete the records for the member ' + CheckBoxName + ' ?'

                    $("#"+ModalId).remove();
                    //Create dynamic pop up based on each Pension ID which is selected on Html Table
                    BootstrapModalPopUp(ModalId, ModalConfirmID, ModalCancelID, 'Cancel', 'Delete Confirmation', ModalMessage);
                });

                var checkBoxID = $('#' + checkBoxVals[0]).attr('id');
                CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,checkBoxVals,checkBoxID,PageActions.OnDelete,Controllers.CommutedPensions,"OnDelete");
            }
            else {

                //do something
            }
        });
    }


//Create alerts
function CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,CheckBoxArray,checkBoxID,PageAction,ControllerName,ActionName)
{
    var checkBoxValue  = $('#' + checkBoxID).val();

    var index = CheckBoxArray.indexOf(checkBoxID);

    //Again get the new ID
    checkBoxID = $('#' + CheckBoxArray[index+1]).attr('id');

    if(checkBoxValue != undefined)
    {
        var ModalId = ModalIdBeforeCreation + checkBoxValue;
        var ModalConfirmID =ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation + checkBoxValue;
        var ModalCancelID = ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation+ checkBoxValue;

        $('#myModal'+ModalId).modal('show');

        //On Confirm Click
        $('#myModal' + ModalId).on('click', '#btn' + ModalConfirmID, function () {

            AjaxRequestToControllerAction(ControllerName,ActionName,PageAction,checkBoxValue);

            CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,CheckBoxArray,checkBoxID,PageAction,ControllerName,ActionName);
        });

        //Popup Cancel button click event
        $('#myModal' + ModalId).on('click', '#btn'+ModalCancelID, function () {

            CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,CheckBoxArray,checkBoxID,PageAction,ControllerName,ActionName);
        });

        //Popup close button click event
        $('#myModal' + ModalId).on('click', '#btn'+ModalCancelID, function () {

            CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,CheckBoxArray,checkBoxID,PageAction,ControllerName,ActionName);
        });

        //When the mouse is clicked out side of the popup
        $('#myModal' + ModalId).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

            CreateAlertsForActions(ModalIdBeforeCreation,ModalConfirmIDBeforeCreation,ModalCancelIDBeforeCreation,CheckBoxArray,checkBoxID,PageAction,ControllerName,ActionName);
        });
    }
}


function AjaxRequestToControllerAction(Controller, ActionMethod, Action, CheckBoxValue) {
$.ajax({
    //The Url action is for the Method FilterTable and the Controller CurrentYearApplications
    //url: '@Url.Action("' + ActionMethod + '", "' + Controller + '")',
    url: '/' + Controller + '/' + ActionMethod + '/',
    //The text from the drop down and the corresponding flag are passed. Flag represents the Index of the value in the dropdown
    data: { ID: CheckBoxValue, PageAction: Action },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //Json data
    datatype: 'json',
    //Specify if the method is GET or POST
    type: 'GET',
    //Error function gets called if there is an error in the ajax request
    error: function (jq, status, message) {
        //Show error
    },

    //Gets called on success of the Ajax Call
    success: function (data) {

    //Do things after success

    }
});
}
```

Everything works fine for me, if there are just 4,5 records selected, but when I select around 10 records and choose to delete them, the first 4,5 work fine, then the popup seems to crash.

Any help in this regard or suggestions for alternative methods to follow would be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you once check the console for logging errors. That can help in debug.

Comment: I dont have any errors, but, sometimes it crashes.